# Gunicorn not using right settings file Django?

Tags: python, django, linux, gunicorn

In my `wsgi.py` I am conditionally setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to two different files(local and production).
On the server I have set "PROD" variable in `/etc/profile`

```
if "PROD" in os.environ:
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
else:
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings_dev")
```

But, still I am getting an error because right settings file is not being set. So maybe if condition isn't working. See below pic.

[image]

My gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/myproject/myproject
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/myproject/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Instead of introducing a new environment variable and load another one based on it, why don't you just set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to the proper value? IMO this is much more clear.

Comment: Yes but based on what condition should i set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE ? I need some differentiator between the two environs (which is "PROD" in the above case) ?

Comment: `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='what.you.want.right.now'` - you usually know which one you need, when you launch your project. Currently you need to specify `PROD` properly.

Comment: I just realised something, wsgi.py i will only use on server(and not locally) then why i need to put condition ? Can't I just hardcode it to settings_production_file.py?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `PROD` environment variable in your Gunicorn configuration this way:

```
[Service]
environment=PROD=True
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/myproject/myproject
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/myproject/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application
```

// EDIT: I overlooked that you set ENV var in `/etc/profile`... You can try my solution, otherwise I will delete my answer.

Comment: Tried this, still same error, if condition not working

Comment: Could you print all your env vars via `print(os.environ)`? Maybe `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is already set. Also you can try to set `myproject.settings` always (in both branches of the condition) and see if that works.

Comment: `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is not in os.environ. But `PROD` is there. 
Also I set myproject.settings in both branches, and it worked.  
So the problem is here only, somehow that condition is failing, though `PROD` variable does exist in os.environ when I check by going in python shell. Puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment variable in `Gunicorn.service` file. From there it can be accessed by Gunicorn.

```
[Service]
...
ExecStart=/virtuall_env_path/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind
unix:/path_to_myproject.sock 
myproject.wsgi:application -e my_var=value -e my_var2=value2
...
```